# LinkedBlockingQueue, items keeps repeating after I take

Tags: java, concurrency

This is my main, and the packaging class. It is supposed to take 6 labelled cans and package it into 1 pack. The problem is the pack number does not increase and my canid keeps repeating after I take it from the pack queue.

```
    public class Assignment_CCP {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            LinkedBlockingQueue<can> presteril = new LinkedBlockingQueue(4);
            LinkedBlockingQueue<can> fill = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
            LinkedBlockingQueue<can> postfill = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
            LinkedBlockingQueue<can> seal = new LinkedBlockingQueue(12);
            LinkedBlockingQueue<can> postseal = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
            LinkedBlockingQueue<can> label = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
            LinkedBlockingQueue<can> postlabel = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
            LinkedBlockingQueue<can> pack = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
            LinkedBlockingQueue<packs> postpack = new LinkedBlockingQueue();

            ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            can filled = null;
            can sealed = null;
            can labeled = null;

            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                can c = new can(i);
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Can" + c.canid + " entered factory");    
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    Future<can> dentscan = exec.submit(new dscanner(c));
                    //Thread.sleep(100);
                    if (dentscan.get() != null) {
                        exec.submit(new sterilisation(presteril, fill, dentscan.get()));
                    }
                    if (fill.isEmpty() != true) {
                        exec.submit(new filling(fill, postfill));
                        Future<can> fillscan = exec.submit(new fscanner(postfill));
                        filled = fillscan.get();
                    }
                    if (filled != null) {
                        exec.submit(new sealing(seal, postseal, filled));
                        if (postseal.isEmpty() != true) {
                            Future<can> sealscan = exec.submit(new sscanner(postseal));
                            sealed = sealscan.get();
                        }
                    }
                    if (sealed != null) {
                        exec.submit(new labelling(label, postlabel, sealed));
                        if (postlabel.isEmpty() != true) {
                            Future<can> labelscan = exec.submit(new lscanner(postlabel));
                            labeled = labelscan.get();
                        }
                    }
                    if(labeled != null){
                        exec.submit(new packaging(pack,postpack,labeled));
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

class packs{

    can c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6;
    int packid;

    public packs(can c1, can c2, can c3, can c4, can c5, can c6, int packid) {
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.c2 = c2;
        this.c3 = c3;
        this.c4 = c4;
        this.c5 = c5;
        this.c6 = c6;
        this.packid = packid;
    }    
}
```

This is the packaging class, it takes 6 cans and passes it to packs class to create a pack object once it reaches the specific number of cans.

```
class packaging implements Runnable{

    LinkedBlockingQueue<can>pack;
    LinkedBlockingQueue<packs>postpack;
    can c;


    public packaging(LinkedBlockingQueue<can> pack, LinkedBlockingQueue<packs> postpack, can c) {
        this.pack = pack;
        this.postpack = postpack;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            int packno =1;
            pack.put(c);
            if(pack.size() == 6){
                System.out.println("Packaging 6 cans into Pack");
                can c1 = pack.take();
                can c2 = pack.take();
                can c3 = pack.take();
                can c4 = pack.take();
                can c5 = pack.take();
                can c6 = pack.take();

                packs pk = new packs(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,packno);
                postpack.put(pk);

                System.out.println("Pack "+packno+": Cans" +c1.canid+", "+ c2.canid+", "+c3.canid+", "+c4.canid+", "+c5.canid+", "+c6.canid);
                packno++;      
            }           
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }

}
```

This is my output. There are 2 cans of number 25 when there is only 1 can with number 25 is generated. The pack number also does not increase.

```
Packaging 6 cans into Pack
Can44 entered factory
Pack 1: Cans20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 25
```

It is supposed to be

```
Pack 3: Cans 20,21,22,23,25,26
```

Comment: What exception was thrown? And why the thread pool, when you are really just doing sequential execution?

Comment: There was no exception thrown. Its a part of my assignment, I need to use thread pool

Comment: How do you know there was no exception when you have an empty catch block?